# Swift Tableview get specific cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to clear a specific cell for my tableview. I know to achieve that by using this code right here:

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: index) as? SomeTableViewCell {
     // do sth
  }else {
     print("Row 1 not found")
}
```

But the problem is when I use this method with a bigger screen phone like Iphone7, 8, X... It'll be working fine but when I tested on iphone5, 6 or the smaller screen that Row 1 is not visible, It'll print that "Row 1 not found"

Comment: In which Func this code you hace written??? Also you want to Remove this specfiic Cell from TableView OR you want to remove only Cell CONTENT? Need clarification...

Comment: If the row isn't visible then there is nothing to do. Just update the data model (in either case).

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz I wrote this code in a function that will call whenever the Notification.addObserver is called. and I want to only change the content inside that specific cell only

Comment: @rmaddy Oh! right, let me try that.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you've almost found the problem yourself!

As with tableviews, the iOS reuses cells them to preserve memory and to offer a seamless smooth scrolling experience to the user.

The iOS reuses the cells when they disappear from the screen. ie: When you scroll down, the initial cells start to be reused. In your larger screens, this takes a while to occur as it may be displaying 20 cells at once vs 10 screens (at once) on your smaller screens.

If you want to permanently remove this cell, then you should remove the corresponding data object from your model which backs up the table view (datasource) and reload the tableview.

If you don't want to permanently remove this cell, then you can reset it only when the table actually needs it to be drawn. This can be done in the datasource method

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
            var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
//Do your Resetting code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the concept, Actually, I did understand the flow of the tableview but I forget that I just use IF LET concept and I do the action only it returns true that's why it's causing this bug. But as @rmaddy pointing out that I should just clear my data and the cell will be reused itself. But your answer did explain the flow that could be helpful for others. I'll vote for your answer too. Thank

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you solved the issue with @rmaddy's help.